# Resize an image with mouse and keeping aspect ratio

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+

I have a custom control that displays an image. The image has a frame around it with 4 size grips in each corner. If the user moves the cursor to a size grip, he should be able to resize the image keeping the aspect ratio.

I already have a resize method that works:

```
public void Resize(float value)
{
    if (value == 0f)
        value = 0.05f;

    //Resize by the same value to keep aspect ratio
    var width = (int)(frame.Width * value);
    var height = (int)(frame.Height * value);

    //Image resizing removed...
}
```

The `Resize` method by itself is working because I can pass any value to it and the aspect ration is maintained. Both `width` and `height` and resized by the same value.

The problem is that the resizing by moving one of the size grips is not working as expected. Also, the image loses its aspect ratio. In the `MouseMove` event I have:

```
if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
{
    //Get mouse position delta
    var x = mousePosition.X - e.Location.X;
    var y = mousePosition.Y - e.Location.Y;

    if (x == 0 && y == 0)
        return;

    bool doY = false;
    var diff = x;

    if (x == 0 && y != 0)
    {
        diff = y;
        doY = true;
    }

    float width = frame.Width + diff;
    float amount = frame.Width / width;

    if (doY)
    {
        float height = frame.Height + diff;
        amount = frame.Height / height;
    }

    Resize(amount);
}
```

When trying the resize by moving the mouse cursor, the aspect ratio is not respected. In the above code I determine whether there was a change in `x` or `y`, and, depending which value changed, I determine the resize value.

Is there a better way to get the correct `x` and `y` deltas and, depending on which grip is being moved, resize the image keeping the aspect ratio?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working as expected"? Also think about that "var x = mousePosition.X - e.Location.X;" could be a negative number, i would use "var x = Math.Abs(mousePosition.X - e.Location.X);".
Can you give us some more info about whats not working and maybe more code for the size grips if they are not working.

Comment: @FSDaniel Yes `x` can be a negative number, which might mean the frame will be resized smaller depending on which size grip is being dragged. The size grips are simply rects drawn on the frame corners and I check which size grip is being dragged by calling the `Contains` method on the rects.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following approach. Create custom control with sizeable style.

```
class SizeablePictureBox : PictureBox
{
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            const int WS_SIZEBOX = 0x40000;

            var cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.Style |= WS_SIZEBOX;

            return cp;
        }
    }
}
```

Place it on the form, set the layout property. When set to `Zoom` aspect ratio will remain the same.

```
var pictureBox = new SizeablePictureBox { Parent = this, Width = 500, Height = 500 };
pictureBox.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Zoom;
pictureBox.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("pic.jpg");
```

Ready! The user can change the size of the control with the mouse. The image dimensions will change automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be overcomplicating the routine. The approach for this should be something simple as:

`Store the initial size of your control on load.`

`On resize, compare the new size of the control and choose the most significant dimension change - width or height - base on some logic, e.g. the biggest one.`

`Calculate the ratio by which the dimension is changed, by comparing its new amount to the stored one.`

`Then apply this ratio by changing the other dimension in code.`

`Finally store the new size for future reference.`

That should do it. No `Mouse_Move` monitoring is necessary.